# Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore via registry

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have tried to install cordova-plugin-jsonstore into a Cordova project. But I am getting the 'Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore via registry'. Check the screenshot.

Command is

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore
```

[image]

Please help to solve the issue. 
Thanks

Comment: What are you npm and node versions?

Comment: see this http://prntscr.com/g00a6c
npm - 5.3.0
node - v6.9.1

Comment: Can you try with node 5.12.0 and npm 3.8.6?

Comment: Yes. I tried to downgrade the npm and node what u mentioned. But node doesnt downgraded. npm is downgraded. 

After that I tried to install jsonstore But I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for the issue

I have downgraded the version from Cordova 7.0.X to Cordova 6.5.0

like below

```
npm install -g cordova@6.5.0
cordova -v
6.5.0
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore
```

It working fine for me.

I got solution from the link
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/385048/facing-issue-while-installing-jsonstore-in-cordova/

Answer (score 0):

Install the version 8.0.2017070506 by using the command

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore@8.0.2017070506`

Comment: Hai Srik, I getting ''Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore@8.0.2017070506 via registry. Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect. Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1''

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081/nexus/cont
ent/groups/mobile-npm-all/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.7.0.tgz failed, reason: getadd
rinfo ENOTFOUND visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com visustar.francelab.fr.ibm.com:8081

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin

Comment: But the network is connected in my system. Other plugins are installed correctly.

Comment: Can you try "npm view cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore versions"? If it lists all the available ones, then chose a specific one - may be older and try